# How to use button to pop up video window(ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to make a button that use the same style but want to use it for two button (1) go to some page (2) to pop up a video trailer. but both of them do the action (1). I don't know how to make these two button do different job.

here is the code for Button,

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const STYLES = ['btn--primary', 'btn--outline', 'btn--test'];

const SIZES = ['btn--medium', 'btn--large'];

export const Button = ({
  children,
  type,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle,
  buttonSize
}) => {
  const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle)
    ? buttonStyle
    : STYLES[0];

  const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

  return (
    <Link to={Button.props.action} className='btn-mobile'>
      <button
        className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
        onClick={onClick}
        type={type}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
    </Link>
    
  );

};
```

here is the code for two buttons

```
function HeroSection() {
  return (
    <div className='hero-container'>
      <video src='/videos/animated-banner.mp4' autoPlay loop muted playsInline/>
      <h1>TITLE</h1>
      <p> simple text.</p>
      <div className='hero-btns'>
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--outline'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
        >
          GET STARTED
        </Button>
        
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--primary'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
          onClick={console.log('hey')}
        >
          WATCH TRAILER <i className='far fa-play-circle' />
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeroSection;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onClick` event for different jobs.

```
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--outline'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
          onClick={() => {
             // ...go to some page...
          }}

        >
          GET STARTED
        </Button>
        
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--primary'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
          onClick={() => {
             // ...open pop up...
          }}
        >
          WATCH TRAILER <i className='far fa-play-circle' />
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I think you could add new props `to` and conditionally use tag either `Link` or `button` by checking that props. If you pass value to props `to` then will be rendered as `Link`, else as `button`

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const STYLES = ['btn--primary', 'btn--outline', 'btn--test'];

const SIZES = ['btn--medium', 'btn--large']

export const Button = ({
  children,
  type,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle,
  buttonSize,
  to
}) => {
  const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle)
    ? buttonStyle
    : STYLES[0];

  const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

  const ActionTag = to ? Link : 'button';

  return (
      <ActionTag
        className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
        onClick={onClick}
        type={type}
        to={to}
      >
        {children}
      </ActionTag>
    
  );

};
```

and you could use that component like this.

- If it's used to navigate to other page, pass value to props `to`
- For popping up a video trailer pass props `onClick`

```js
<Button
  className='btns'
  buttonStyle='btn--outline'
  buttonSize='btn--large'
  onClick={
  // do something
  }
>
  pop up
</Button>

<Button
  className='btns'
  buttonStyle='btn--primary'
  buttonSize='btn--large'
  to="/"
>
  go to home
</Button>
```

Comment: Glad it helped!